# UserMulti Field not allowing multiple inputs

Tags: development, spfield

I am trying to add a muliiple user site column using the following:

```
  <Field
  ID="{FC2612C2-1C60-45C1-949A-A49BECD8DB02}"
  Name="test"
  DisplayName="test"
  Group="test"
  Type="UserMulti"
  SourceID="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3"
    >
  </Field>
```

It is however displaying as a single user select field. What could be wrong?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

John,
 Never tried this myself, but a comment is made http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms437580.aspx stating

"*In order to allow enter multiple values into field with Type="UserMulti"
you must set attribute Mult="TRUE"*."

Comment: Don't know how I missed that

Comment: I tried that in Sharepoint 2013 and it didn't work at first. I was working on a list that uses content types and I was changing the defiitin only for the list template. I set `Mult="TRUE"` for the related site column as well and then it worked. Thanks for the tip there and +1 to you.

Comment: For me it worked only after I've added the field with properties: `Type="User" Mult="TRUE"` (SharePoint 2013)

Comment: The comments on that page have gone now. Cheers for saving this!

Comment: How do we set this in a "fldtypes_*" XML file?

Answer (score 0):

[The answer](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/40283/10435) of [Cann0nF0dder](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/8289/cann0nf0dder) is applicable to fields of type "LookupMulti" too. I allready tried. For short:

*"In order to allow enter multiple values into field with Type="UserMulti" you must set attribute Mult="TRUE"."* on my revised case is valid too for: "...Type="LookupMulti"..."